# Fadeout page after animation finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want an animation (`function handleScreen(mql)`) to run and after it is completed, for the page (`#splash,#name`) to fade out after 1 sec. I tried adding a `.promise` function but that doesn't seem to work. Any help would be very much appreciated. https://jsfiddle.net/Dar_T/eqdk82ru/1/

```
handleScreen(mql).promise().done(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
        $("#name,#splash").fadeOut("slow");
     }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what `handleScreen` returns :

In jQuery :

> The .promise() method returns a dynamically generated Promise that is
>   resolved once all actions of a certain type bound to the collection,
>   queued or not, have ended.
>
> By default, type is "fx", which means the returned Promise is resolved when >all animations of the selected elements have completed.
>   in jQuery you can check `:animated`.

So it should be :

```
handleScreen(mql).promise().done(function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
            $("#name,#splash").fadeOut("slow");
        }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: I gave that a try (https://jsfiddle.net/Dar_T/eqdk82ru/). The fade doesn't seem to happen though. The script is at the bottom after all the minified js.